# Laravel Printing out table_1 values that do not exist in table_2

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, laravel-4

I have 2 databases (AccessControls & User).

AccessControl table has this fields: AC_id, User_id, AccessControls.

User table has this fields: User_id, User_name, UserType.

What I wanted to achieve is: 
- **Printing out users that has a UserType = 1 (in user table) and User_id which does not exist in AccessControl table.**

The results will be stored in a table in my view.blade.php

In the meantime, I managed to get the 1st part, which is users with UserType = 1. However, I have no idea on how I could get the 2nd part, which is to check if the User_id exists in AccessControl table.

Inside my controller:

```
$user = UserEntry::where('UserType', '=', 1)->get();
```

I have a rough idea that the query should be something like:

> Select statement Where user.User_id != AccessControl.User_id

Any ideas on how I could achieve both parts in a single query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either `not exists`

```
User::where('UserType',1)
   ->whereNotExists(function ($q) {
       $q->from('AccessControl')
         ->where('AccessControl.User_id', DB::raw('users.id'));
   })
   ->get();
```

or `leftJoin`:

```
User::where('UserType',1)
  ->leftJoin('AccessControl','AccessControll.User_id','=','users.id')
  ->whereNull('AccessControll.id')
  ->get(['users.*']);
```

Check performance, suppose left join will be faster.

Comment: Thanks a lot @deczo!! Appreciate your help! :)

Answer (score 0):

The SQL way would be a LEFT JOIN in combination with ISNULL():

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    users
LEFT JOIN
    AccessControl
ON
    user.User_id  = AccessControl.User_id
WHERE
   users.userType = 1
AND
   AccessControl.User_id IS NULL
```

I'm sure you get this translated to laravel.